# Load WebView2 in async manner in WPF MVVM Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, webview2

I am trying to use MVVM pattern to create a WebView2 based application -
Somehow I am not able to see the WebView2 view getting loaded into the app. App continues to show the loader screen.

WebView2 loading is async operation and it takes time - so how can I optimize it's loading with parallelization ( load as early as possible ) and showing loader using MVVM pattern.

When webview2 is finally loaded set it's source to some url.

I am using **Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm** library ( PS: I am new to MVVM pattern :)

This is what I tried -

View:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow1" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local11:LoaderVM}">
        <local1:Loader/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local11:WebViewVM}">
        <wv2:WebView2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
        <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class MainWindow1VM : ObservableObject
{
    private object _currentView;
    public object CurrentView
    {
        get => _currentView;
        set => SetProperty(ref _currentView, value);
    }

    private readonly object _loader;
    private readonly WebView2 _webView;

    public MainWindow1VM()
    {
        _loader = new Loader();
        CurrentView = _loader;

        _webView = new WebView2();

        _ = WvUtils.SetupWebView(_webView);

        //await WvUtils.SetupWebView(webView);
        _webView.Loaded += (o, e) =>
        {
            WvUtils.SetWebView2CommonSettings(_webView);
            _webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://example.com");
        };

        _webView.NavigationCompleted += NavigationCompletedEventHandler;

    }

    private void NavigationCompletedEventHandler(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        CurrentView = _webView;
    }

}


public class WebViewVM : ObservableObject
{
}



public class LoaderVM : ObservableObject
    {
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear what your LoaderVM and WebViewVM are supposed to be good for, as they are never used. Your current MainWindow1VM only returns two different view objects by its  CurrentView property. Hence also the two DataTemplates are useless. You may however want to change your approach into a real MVVM solution, where the main view model provides child view models via a property.

Comment: I followed an example and based that I tried to implement that. Any better solution or approach definitely I am open to explore.

Comment: Did you check if the NavigationCompletedEventHandler is called at all?

Comment: It is never called.

Comment: I supposed that not even the Loaded handler is called, because _webView is never added to the UI.

Comment: yes you are right, it is not called. How should I add it?

Comment: The whole approach is broken. Can't you just add a WebView2 element to the UI as usual and overlay it with a "loader screen" which you remove when loading has finished?

Comment: What about this one here webview2 is added `  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local11:WebViewVM}">
        <wv2:WebView2 />
    </DataTemplate>`?

Comment: As said, those DataTemplates are not used at all. You can simply remove them.

Comment: What if I want to use `DataTemplate` what do I need to fix?

Comment: See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Not sure however whether data templating would make sense in your scenario.